# Data structure to implement for millions of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, data-structures

> There are 1000 students attempting x questions in a competitive examination, where x is your birthdate coded as ddmmyyyy format. For example if your birthday was on 11/12/2000, then x=11122000. Each student can score one mark per right answer, and a penalty of-0.5 marks per wrong answer. The negative marks increases per wrong answer as a penalty p=0.5*n, where n represents the n'th wrong answer. The questions are categorised into 5 topics, with number of questions in the categories in the ratio 10:4:3:2:1. All the questions are multiple choice questions (MCQ) type, with possibly more than one correct answer.

I tried implementing the following approach but it is taking long time to execute since the data is very high. Any other method to implement?

```
import random

userInput = int(input("Enter a DOB:"))
ratio = [10,4,3,2,1]
nQues = []
for r in ratio:
    input1 = int((r/20)*userInput )
    nQues.append(input1)
    print('catogorise')
    print(input1)

nStud = 10

que = []
ans = []

for i in range(userInput):
     quesOption = random.randint(1,4)
     que.append(quesOption)
        
     ansOption = random.randint(1,4)
     ans.append(ansOption)
        

correct = []
incorrect = []

category1 = {}
category2 = {}
category3 = {}
category4 = {}
category5 = {}
   
correctMarks = 0
incorrectMarks = 0
noOfIncorrect = 0

a=0

for n in nQues:
    b=n
   
    for j in range(nStud):    
        
        for i in range(a,b):  #(n)
            if que[i] == ans[i] :
                correct.append(i+1)
                correctMarks += 1
            
            if que[i] != ans[i] :
                incorrect.append(i+1)
                noOfIncorrect += 1
                incorrectMarks += 0.5*(noOfIncorrect)
            totMarks = correctMarks - incorrectMarks
        
            # category1[j+1] = totMarks
        
            if n == nQues[0]:
                category1[j+1] = totMarks
                # print("CAt1 finihed")
        
            if n == nQues[1]:
                category2[j+1] = totMarks
                # print("CAt2 finihed")
            
            if n == nQues[2]:
                category3[j+1] = totMarks
                # print("CAt3 finihed")
            
            if n == nQues[3]:
                category4[j+1] = totMarks
                # print("CAt4 finihed")
            
            if n == nQues[4]:
                category5[j+1] = totMarks
                # print("CAt5 finihed")
            a = n+1
  
    
    
print(que)
print(ans)       
print(correct)
print(incorrect)
print(correctMarks)
print(incorrectMarks)
print(totMarks)
print(category1)
print(category2)
```

Comment: The structure depends on what you intend to do with the data.  The way the problem statement is formulated, it would take students over 2.6 years to answer the x questions if they take 5 seconds per questions 16 hours per day 7 days a week.  Do you need to simulate the results ?  compute statistics ? Also, what is the distribution of multiple right answers ?

Comment: We would also have to decide how good the students are, in order to perform a simulation.  If none of them studied anything and just answer randomly, then a flat probability distribution would work otherwise a normal distribution would be in order.

Comment: currently all your students are giving the same answers? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to clean it up a bit, and rename the variables, so it would be easier to understand. Also I randomized the answers for each student

```py
import random

userInput = int(input("Enter a DOB:"))
questionRatio = [10,4,3,2,1]
questionsPerCategory = [int((r/20)*userInput) for r in questionRatio]

numberStudents = 10

# initialize the solutions for the questions randomly
solutions = [random.randint(1,4) for i in range(userInput)]
# initialize the answers of the students randomly 
# (if the same answers for each student are needed as before change to):
# studentAnswers = [[random.randint(1,4) for i in range(userInput)] * numberStundents]
studentAnswers = [[random.randint(1,4) for i in range(userInput)] for j in range(numberStudents)]

category1 = {}
category2 = {}
category3 = {}
category4 = {}
category5 = {}

#Save correct, incorrect noOfIncorrect, totalMark per student
correctMarksForStudent = dict(zip(range(1,numberStudents+1),[0]*numberStudents))
noOfIncorrectForStudent = dict(zip(range(1,numberStudents+1),[0]*numberStudents))
incorrectMarksForStudent = dict(zip(range(1,numberStudents+1),[0]*numberStudents))
totalMarksForStudent = dict(zip(range(1,numberStudents+1),[0]*numberStudents))

# we iterate over the solutions, with the indices of the solutions
for index, solution in enumerate(solutions):   
    # we check every studentAnswer for their answer at the current index, and compare them to the solution for current index
    for studentNumber, studentAnswer in enumerate(studentAnswers):
        # Print for Debug purposes
#print("Checking Student", studentNumber+1, "Index", index, studentAnswer[index], solutions[index])
        if studentAnswer[index] == solution:
            # For correct answers increase the correctMarks for this student by one
            correctMarksForStudent[studentNumber+1] += 1
        else:
            # For incorrectAnswers increase the number of incorrect answers for this student by one
            noOfIncorrectForStudent[studentNumber+1] += 1
            # Then add to the already incorrectMarks 0.5 times the no of incorrect answers (this gets big fast)
            incorrectMarksForStudent[studentNumber+1] += 0.5 * noOfIncorrectForStudent[studentNumber+1]
        # update the total mark of the student by setting it to correctMark - incorrectMark
        totalMarksForStudent[studentNumber+1] = correctMarksForStudent[studentNumber+1] - incorrectMarksForStudent[studentNumber+1]
        # print for Debug purposes
#print("Total For Student", studentNumber+1, totalMarksForStudent[studentNumber+1])
        # updating the correct Category at the student index with the new totalMarks of the student
        if index < questionsPerCategory[0]:
            category1[studentNumber+1] = totalMarksForStudent[studentNumber+1]
        elif index < questionsPerCategory[0] + questionsPerCategory[1]:
            category2[studentNumber+1] = totalMarksForStudent[studentNumber+1]
        elif index < questionsPerCategory[0] + questionsPerCategory[1] + questionsPerCategory[2]:
            category3[studentNumber+1] = totalMarksForStudent[studentNumber+1]
        elif index < questionsPerCategory[0] + questionsPerCategory[1] + questionsPerCategory[2] + questionsPerCategory[3]:
            category4[studentNumber+1] = totalMarksForStudent[studentNumber+1]
        else:
            category5[studentNumber+1] = totalMarksForStudent[studentNumber+1]
    
# printing the solutions and the student answers takes a lot of time and terminal space

#print("Solutions",solutions)
#print("StudentAnswers",studentAnswers)     
print("CorrectMark",correctMarksForStudent)
print("IncorrectMarks",incorrectMarksForStudent)
print("StudentMarks",totalMarksForStudent)
print("Category1",category1)
print("Category2",category2)
print("Category3",category3)
print("Category4",category4)
print("Category5",category5)
```

But this still takes very long (approx 2 min for me) and as I'm unsure, what the endresult should look like, this is all I can get out of it. But maybe this will help you or somebody else, figure out a better way. I'm not sure which one is better practice, to iterate over every solution and check the answer for each student, or iterate over each student and check the solution for each given answer. There maybe some performance improvements possible

Example output:

```
Enter a DOB:08071994
CorrectMark {1: 2018876, 2: 2017217, 3: 2019374, 4: 2017334, 5: 2018198, 6: 2018962, 7: 2017675, 8: 2018907, 9: 2019666, 10: 2016580}
IncorrectMarks {1: 9160060893760.5, 2: 9165082643626.5, 3: 9158553729255.0, 4: 9164728442565.0, 5: 9162113015853.0, 6: 9159800611514.0, 7: 9163696152020.0, 8: 9159967070664.0, 9: 9157670067978.0, 10: 9167011191702.5}
StudentMarks {1: -9160058874884.5, 2: -9165080626409.5, 3: -9158551709881.0, 4: -9164726425231.0, 5: -9162110997655.0, 6: -9159798592552.0, 7: -9163694134345.0, 8: -9159965051757.0, 9: -9157668048312.0, 10: -9167009175122.5}
Category1 {1: -2291264732790.5, 2: -2290928705099.0, 3: -2289516750015.5, 4: -2291965626589.0, 5: -2290094796904.0, 6: -2291553857417.0, 7: -2290554865412.0, 8: -2288873720765.5, 9: -2287783047122.0, 10: -2292098853947.0}
Category2 {1: -4489931797886.0, 2: -4491550819509.0, 3: -4486677684734.0, 4: -4490156409103.5, 5: -4490175480126.0, 6: -4489135109064.0, 7: -4490128862142.5, 8: -4486618375911.0, 9: -4483367581308.5, 10: -4493394825181.5}
Category3 {1: -6618527592931.0, 2: -6623800004942.5, 3: -6616937789939.5, 4: -6620431491756.0, 5: -6619860293359.5, 6: -6618211160609.5, 7: -6621028446142.0, 8: -6615397046632.0, 9: -6612452385439.5, 10: -6624265848443.5}
Category4 {1: -8267619890383.5, 2: -8273785786215.5, 3: -8265316896835.5, 4: -8270291304668.0, 5: -8268056949093.5, 6: -8266360535811.0, 7: -8270711178658.5, 8: -8264977656482.0, 9: -8263226941953.5, 10: -8274205748901.0}
Category5 {1: -9160058874884.5, 2: -9165080626409.5, 3: -9158551709881.0, 4: -9164726425231.0, 5: -9162110997655.0, 6: -9159798592552.0, 7: -9163694134345.0, 8: -9159965051757.0, 9: -9157668048312.0, 10: -9167009175122.5}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now got the solution

Comment: If my answer helped, I would appreciate it, if you could show that somehow. If not, you could post your own solution, so that anyone who stumbles upon similiar problems may find a solution :)